# How to checkbox enable/disable with Struts 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, checkbox, struts2

I would like to show 2 checkboxs in my page (called `box1` and `box2`). The default value is `box1 = false` and `box2 = false`. But I also have to enable `box2` only if `box1 = true`. So I have created the following JS function :

```js
function myTest() {
  var check = document.getElementById('box1');
  if (check.checked == false) {
    $('#box2').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#box2').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

Now I don't really understand how to use `myTest` function in the JSP file. I have tried to use it with `onload="myTest()"` as follow, but it doesn't work (`box2` is always disabled).

```html
<body onload="myTest()" />

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label required">
        <s:text name="box1" />
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <s:checkbox id="box1" name="box1"> </s:checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label required">
        <s:text name="box2" />
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <s:checkbox id="box2" name="box2"></s:checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using jQuery in the page. Here is my solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // on page load unchecking and disabling box2
    $("#box2").prop("checked", false);
    $("#box2").prop("disabled", true);
});



$("#box1").on("change", function(){
    if ($(this).prop("checked")){
        // box1 is checked
        $("#box2").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else{
        // box1 is not checked
        $("#box2").prop("checked", false);
        $("#box2").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: You can't set property values arbitrary without getting them from the `ValueStack`.

Answer (score 0):

There is `onchange` attribute for [`<s:checkbox>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/checkbox-tag.html) which is used for

> Set the html onchange attribute on rendered html element

This tag generates a simple input field of `checkbox` type.

> Renders an HTML input element of type `checkbox`, populated by the specified property from the `ValueStack`.

The action bean is on top of the `ValueStack`, so you can get the specified property there.

To define JS function in JSP you should use html `<script>` tag. You can do it in the `<head>` tag or after the rendered element.

```
<s:checkbox id="box1" name="box1" onchange="myTest()"/>
<s:checkbox id="box2" name="box2" %{box1?'':'disabled="disabled"'}/>

<script>
  function myTest() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") === "checked") {
      $("#box2").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#box2").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
  }
</script>
```